# MySQL - retrieving rows ordered by greatest value of a variable series of columns

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I am having a quite difficult time with a particular MySQL query.
Here is the structure of 3 tables I need to join and sort rows from:

```
users
ID    username

routes
ID    val_1       val_2      val_3       val_4

scores
ID    route_id    user_id    route_level
```

This query is for a leaderboard feature, and needs to return a list of user IDs ordered by their best score. One user may have several scores, and we need to find the best score.

The twist is the "route_level" part: if the value of this column is for example "2", then we need to go to the corresponding route_id, and find the greatest value between val_1 and val_2. We must go no higher than val_x, x being the value of column scores.route_level.

Also, val_x is not an int (the value is usually something like "6A+", the next bigger value being 6B, then 6B+ etc.), and val_x is not necessarily smaller than val_x+1.

Here is as far as I got, but it doesn't work (I get results all over the place, not ordered at all, at least not in a way I can make any sense of):

```
SELECT u.*, r.val_1 AS v1, r.val_2 AS v2, r.val_3 AS v3, r.val_4 AS v4 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN scores s
ON s.user_id = u.ID
INNER JOIN routes r
ON s.route_id = r.ID
GROUP BY u.ID
ORDER BY GREATEST(v1, v2, v3, v4) DESC
```

Does any of you have an idea of how I might take this on in a single MySQL query?

Thanks! :-)

Edit: here is a [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8366a)

Comment: I think that should work. Could you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: You are misusing a MySQL-specific extension to `GROUP BY`. This is undoubtedly causing your query to return unpredictable values for the `val_n` columns in your query. Please read this.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your aggregate query right in order to get your ordering right. Try this. It will handle the aggregation by user correctly, and pull the maximum `val_n` score for each user.

```
SELECT u.ID, u.username, 
       MAX(r.val_1) AS v1,
       MAX(r.val_2) AS v2, 
       MAX(r.val_3) AS v3, 
       MAX(r.val_4) AS v4 
  FROM users u
 INNER JOIN scores s  ON s.user_id = u.ID
 INNER JOIN routes r ON s.route_id = r.ID
 GROUP BY u.ID ,u.username
 ORDER BY GREATEST( MAX(r.val_1), MAX(r.val_2), MAX(r.val_3), MAX(r.val_4)) DESC
```

**Edit** I missed the bit about the route_level ... focused too much on the query in your question, not the text.

But it's not tremendously hard apply. It needs to be applied row-by-row, at the detail level, BEFORE the aggregation function `MAX()`. That can be done, I believe, by changing the `SELECT` part of your query as follows.

```
SELECT u.ID, u.username, 
       MAX(GREATEST (
           IF(r.route_level>=1, r.val_1, NULL)
           IF(r.route_level>=2, r.val_2, NULL)
           IF(r.route_level>=3, r.val_3, NULL)
           IF(r.route_level>=4, r.val_4, NULL) )) AS val
  FROM users u
 INNER JOIN scores s  ON s.user_id = u.ID
 INNER JOIN routes r ON s.route_id = r.ID
 GROUP BY u.ID ,u.username
 ORDER BY MAX(GREATEST (
           IF(r.route_level>=1, r.val_1, NULL)
           IF(r.route_level>=2, r.val_2, NULL)
           IF(r.route_level>=3, r.val_3, NULL)
           IF(r.route_level>=4, r.val_4, NULL) ))
```

I also missed the point about your `val_n` values being `varchar()` values rather than integers. That one is harder. When you use `MAX()` on `varchar()` values, it employs the collation. All character collations I know of will declare that the value `6B+`, for example, is larger than `10B+`, because `6` is greater than `1`.

I am sorry, I don't know of any elegant SQL magic that can make that work better.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, this almost works indeed, but doesn't take into account the scores.route_level value. As you can see in the SQLFiddle link I added in my question, user "TEST" has the highest score although he only went to val_1, so val_2 should be discarded here. The highest score should be held by user "The Master Ben" (8B+).

Comment: Great, @frsechet, I think you've probably now used StackOverflow to get some ideas about how to solve your fairly complex problem. Considering its complexity, you may want to consider using a host language (php, java, etc) to do this analysis.  It's not a good use of SO to keep coming back saying, "close, but you don't have it yet." Instead, you should be able to finish your project now.

Comment: In fact I did find the solution (see above), thanks to you! I was just pointing out the fact that this solution was not complete for my problem, but it did put me on the right track, so I posted the solution when I found it... I wasn't asking of you to do the work for me! Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks really close...

But you need an aggregate function to get the "best score".  (Databases other than MySQL would object to your statement, griping about references to non-aggregates not included in the GROUP BY...)

The "twist" about the `route_level` is a bit tricky. I'd handle that first, to get the "best" score from each row. I'd use an expressions like these:

```
IF(r.route_level>=1,r.val_1,NULL)
IF(r.route_level>=2,r.val_2,NULL)
IF(r.route_level>=3,r.val_3,NULL)
IF(r.route_level>=4,r.val_4,NULL)
```

Those expressions conditionally return a value from the particular `val_N` column, depending on the value of `route_level`. Since you don't need to return the individual values, you could wrap all of those expressions in that convenient `GREATEST()` function.

```
GREATEST( IF(r.route_level>=1,r.val_1,NULL)
        , IF(r.route_level>=2,r.val_2,NULL)
        , IF(r.route_level>=3,r.val_3,NULL)
        , IF(r.route_level>=4,r.val_4,NULL)
        , ...
        )
```

That would get the "best score" from each row.  All that remains now is to find the "best score" from the multiple rows returned for a given user. And we can use the MAX aggregate to do that.

So, the only change you need to make to your query would be to replace the expression in the ORDER BY clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT u.ID
  FROM users u
  JOIN scores s
    ON s.user_id = u.ID
  JOIN routes r
    ON s.route_id = r.ID
 GROUP BY u.ID
 ORDER BY MAX( GREATEST( IF(r.route_level>=1,r.val_1,NULL)
                       , IF(r.route_level>=2,r.val_2,NULL)
                       , IF(r.route_level>=3,r.val_3,NULL)
                       , IF(r.route_level>=4,r.val_4,NULL)
                       )
             ) DESC
```

(Also remove all those val_1, val_2, et al. expressions from the SELECT list. It's indeterminate which row those will be returned from. None of those values may be the "best score". If you want to also return the value of the "best score", then use that same expression in the ORDER BY in the SELECT list.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work alone, although as you said, it does look really close :-). It still gets results all over the place, not ordered at all... But the thought process helped me get way closer though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from Ollie Jones and spencer7593, I figured the answer to my own question:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.username, s.route_level,
   GREATEST( IF(s.route_level >= 1, MAX(r.val_1), 0)
            , IF(s.route_level >= 2, MAX(r.val_2), 0)
            , IF(s.route_level >= 3, MAX(r.val_3), 0)
            , IF(s.route_level >= 4, MAX(r.val_4), 0)
            ) AS vmax
 FROM users u
 INNER JOIN scores s  ON s.user_id = u.ID
 INNER JOIN routes r ON s.route_id = r.ID
 GROUP BY u.ID
 ORDER BY vmax DESC
```

This gives the max value AS vmax, taking into account the route_length value for each row, and orders the results correctly.

Thanks everyone for your participation! :-)